# Django APP Heroku Log detecting duplicated requests

Tags: django, heroku

I have a Django APP running on Heroku. I noticed that when I make some requests, there seems to be a sort of duplicated call with extra info in the url. Which of course is not found.

I will explain here showing Heroku´s log details.

The first request works fine and the APP does what it´s supposed to do. Notice the path ending: `/3/`

```
2021-05-28T00:05:49.833310+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/catalog/toma-pedidok-detail/7650/Proxima%20fase/3/" host=www.host.com request_id=ef1018b5-456a-4559-89e6-830b256671fd fwd="181.168.190.149" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1971ms status=200 bytes=160294 protocol=https
```

Then the "ghost" request happens and the path ending has the extra characters: `/3/636`

```
2021-05-28T00:06:02.494246+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/catalog/toma-pedidok-detail/7650/Proxima%20fase/3/636" host=www.host.com request_id=222035b1-2ea8-405d-b8b2-c47fc2376aba fwd="181.168.190.149" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=83ms status=404 bytes=11585 protocol=https
```

Finaly we have a logical "not found" response.

```
2021-05-28T00:06:02.491918+00:00 app[web.1]: Not Found: /catalog/toma-pedidok-detail/7650/Proxima fase/3/636
```

**Some checks**

- It happens sometimes, not always
- There is no ajax call related with this url target
- Django´s view only has 1 return statement

I don´t include all the view because it´s quite extense. I´m trying to get a clue about why can this be happening first.

Any clues welcome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: I worked it out but I can't recall the actual problem. Sorry.